# Is there any rest end point where I can find if the id I have is a file or a folder for onedrive/sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I have an id(fdxxxf8-6xxb-4xx0-8xx9-9xxx8) which i got from one of the API response. Is there anyway to figure it out if the id is of a file or a folder?
I need to call to different API based on if it is a folder or a file

Answer (score 0):

We can use the OneDrive API like below, if the Response data contains **file** property, the id is of a file, if the Response data contains **folder** property, the id is of a folder.

```
/me/drive/items/{item-id}?$select=file,folder
```

Reference: [Get a DriveItem resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online)